# Template class initialization in main

Tags: c++, copy-constructor, template-classes

```
class Q
{

Q(const Q &obj) {} // copy constructor 
Q& operator= (const Q& a){} // equal op overload
}

template <class T>
class B{
   public : T x;
 B<T>(T t) {
      //  x = t; }
    
}
int main()
{
    Q a(2);
    a.init(1,0);
    a.init(2,1);
    B <Q> aa(a); // this line gives error
}
```

How to initialize template class with copy constructor? B  aa(a); // this line gives error
I want to solve it but I could not.
Error:

no matching function for call to 'Q::Q()'|
candidate: Q::Q(const Q&)|

candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided|
candidate: Q::Q(int)|

candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided|

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To **solve** the mentioned error just add a **default constructor** inside class `Q` as shown below

```
class Q
{
    Q() //default constructor
    {
      //some code here if needed
    }

    //other members as before
};
```

The default constructor is needed because when your write :

```
B <Q> aa(a);
```

then the template paramter `T` is deduced to be of type `Q` and since you have

```
T x;
```

inside the class template `B`, it tries to use the default constructor of type `T` which is nothing but `Q` in this case , so this is why you need default constructor for `Q`.

**Second** note that your copy constructor should have a `return` statement which it currently do not have.

Comment: yes it solved the problem but which line is calling default constructor?

Comment: @elections12 I have added the reason why we need the default constructor for `Q` in my answer. Check it out. Basically, when you write `B <Q> aa(a);` then the template parameter `T` is deduced to be of type `Q` and since you have `T x;` inside the class tempalte `B`, it tries to use the default constructor of type `T` which is nothing but `Q` in this case. So this is why we need the default constructor of `Q`.